# How to code dynamic number of WHEN evaluations in PySpark for a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of historical values for a device setting and a dataframe with timestamps.

I need to create a new column in my dataframe based on the comparison of the timestamps column in the dataframe and the timestamp of the setting value in my list.

```
settings_history = [[1, '2021-01-01'], [2, '2021-01-12']]

dataframe = df.withColumn(
   'setting_col', when(col('device_timestamp') <= settings_history[0][1], settings_history[0][0])
                  .when(col('device_timestamp') <= settings_history[1][1], settings_history[1][0])
)
```

The number of entries in the `settings_history` array is dynamic and I need to find a way to implement something like above, but I get a syntax error. Also, I have tried to use a *for* loop in my withColumn function, but that didn't work either.

My raw dataframe has values like:

```
device_timestamp
2020-05-21
2020-12-19
2021-01-03
2021-01-11
```

My goal is to have something like:

```
device_timestamp    setting_col
2020-05-21          1
2020-12-19          1
2021-01-03          2
2021-01-11          2
```

I'm using Databricks on Azure for my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to chain the `when` conditions together:

```
from functools import reduce

settings_history = [[1, '2021-01-01'], [2, '2021-01-12']]

new_col = reduce(
    lambda c, history: c.when(col('device_timestamp') <= history[1], history[0]), 
    settings_history[1:], 
    when(col('device_timestamp') <= settings_history[0][1], settings_history[0][0])
)

dataframe = df.withColumn('setting_col', new_col)
```

Comment: How about adding an `.otherwise()` condition? I realised that everything after the `2021-01-12` value should still be set to a value of `2`. I currently accomplished this by using another `when()` with the inverse equality comparison, but it's a bit strange when reading the code and maybe a bit harder to understand. I tried adding a simple `.otherwise()` after the end of the `when`, but I received a syntax error.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu you should add `.otherwise()` after `reduce(...)`, like `reduce(...).otherwise(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below created `when_expression` function will be useful in this case. where a `when` condition is created based on whatever information you provide in list `settings_array`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def when_expression(settings_array):
    when_condition = None
    for a, b in settings_array:
        if when_condition is None:
            when_condition = F.when(F.col('device_timestamp') <=  a, F.lit(b))
        else:
            when_condition = when_condition.when(F.col('device_timestamp') <= a, F.lit(b))
    return when_condition

settings_array = [
    [2, 3], # if <= 2 make it 3
    [5, 7], # if <= 5 make it 7
    [10, 100], # if <= 10 make it 100
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'device_timestamp': range(10)})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
df.show()

when_condition = when_expression(settings_array)
print(when_condition)

df = df.withColumn('setting_col', when_condition)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+
|device_timestamp|
+----------------+
|               0|
|               1|
|               2|
|               3|
|               4|
|               5|
|               6|
|               7|
|               8|
|               9|
+----------------+

Column<b'CASE WHEN (device_timestamp <= 2) THEN 3 WHEN (device_timestamp <= 5) THEN 7 WHEN (device_timestamp <= 10) THEN 100 END'>
+----------------+-----------+
|device_timestamp|setting_col|
+----------------+-----------+
|               0|          3|
|               1|          3|
|               2|          3|
|               3|          7|
|               4|          7|
|               5|          7|
|               6|        100|
|               7|        100|
|               8|        100|
|               9|        100|
+----------------+-----------+
```